# Is it possible to write a C++ .dll library to export methods which is written within namespace and class?

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, dll

I am newbie to C++ `dll` concept, just want to know, is it possible to write a C++ .dll library to export method which is written inside a namespace and a class?

What I have tried...

```
/*JNLib.h Header File*/
#ifndef __JNLIB_H__
#define __JNLIB_H__
#include <string>
#include <vector>
using namespace std;

    namespace JNLib
    {
        class __declspec(dllexport) JNLibClass
        {
        public:
                void split_string();
        };
    }

#endif
```

and inside .cpp file

```
/*JNLib.cpp File*/
#include "stdafx.h"
#include "JNLib.h"

    namespace JNLib
    {
        void JNLibClass::split_string()
        {
            cout<<"Library called"<<std::endl;
        }
    }
```

Now I am able to compile this project and getting `.dll` file successfully. In another project, I am able to load library (`.dll`) file successfully by using `LoadLibrary()` method but `GetProcAddress` method returns null each time. The code I have written is

```
typedef void (CALLBACK  *f_funci)();
HINSTANCE dllinstance = LoadLibrary(L"..\\myLIB\\JNLib.dll");
f_funci funci = (f_funci)GetProcAddress(dllinstance, "split_string");
```

Please let me know what I am doing wrong.

Comment: Lookup symbol mangling. You can also use the dumpbin tool on Windows (comes with Visual Studio) to check the symbol names that are actually exported.

Comment: Besides the [name-mangling](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Name_mangling) issue you have another problem loading that function. The problem is that you try to load a non-static member function as it were a non-member function. Non-static member functions needs an *object* to be called on.

Comment: Why don't you Include the header files (with `dllimport` instead of `dllexport`) and link to the dll?

Comment: Here is a nice walkthrough by Microsoft: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms235636.aspx

Comment: As Some programmer dude said, `split_string` is a non-static member function. Remember that, unlike languages such as C#, C++ allows non-member functions. In other words, if `JNLibClass` exists purely as a place to put some utility functions, you can get rid of it.

Answer (score 1):

There is no symbol called `split_string` in the library - the name has been [mangled](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Name_mangling).

You can use the `dumpbin` tool on the DLL to see what symbols are exported. Alternatively, you can move what you want to export out the namespace/class and into an `extern "C"` block (which stops the name mangling).

Answer (score 1):

It is possible to export a method within its namespace from a DLL.
First, define your method with your namespace, and as @OMGtechy wrote above - add the `extern "C"` decoration:

```
namespace MyNameSpace{
    extern "C" void foo();
}
```

Second, edit your project `def` file to specify your namespace mapping:

```
LIBRARY MyDllName
EXPORTS
    MyNameSpace::foo=foo
```

Now, when loading your method specify your namespace:

```
typedef void(*PFN_MYFUNC)();

HINSTANCE  hLib = ::LoadLibrary("MyDllName");
PFN_MYFUNC pfn  = (PFN_MYFUNC)::GetProcAddress( hLib, "MyNameSpace::foo");
```